# JSON/PrototypeJS - why does this only work SOMETIMES?

Tags: javascript, json, prototypejs

This is driving me nuts!

I'm getting some JSON from my server:

---

```
{"id262":{"done":null,"status":null,"verfall":null,"id":262,"bid":20044,"art":"owner","uid":"demo02","aktion":null,"termin_datum":null,"docid":null,"gruppenid":null,"news":"newsstring","datum":"11.06.2010","header":"headerstring","for_uid":"demo01"},

"id263":{"done":null,"status":"pending","verfall":null,"bid":20044,"id":263,"uid":"demo02","art":"foo","aktion":"dosomething","termin_datum":"11.06.2010","docid":null,"gruppenid":null,"datum":"11.06.2010","news":"newsstring","for_uid":"demo01","header":"headerstring"},

"id261":{"done":null,"status":null,"verfall":null,"id":261,"bid":20044,"art":"termin","uid":"demo02","aktion":null,"termin_datum":"25.06.2010","docid":null,"gruppenid":null,"news":"newsstring","datum":"11.06.2010","header":"headerstring","for_uid":null}}
```

---

This is how my JS looks like:

```
var user = 'demo02';

 new Ajax.Request('myscript.pl?someparameter=value', { method:'get', 
    onSuccess: function(transport){
        var db_json = transport.responseText.evalJSON(),
            propCount = 0,
            someArray1 = [],
            someArray2 = [],
            otherArray = [];

        //JSON DEBUG
        console.log('validated string:');
        console.log(transport.responseText.evalJSON(true));

        for(var prop in db_json) { 
        propCount++;
            if  ( (db_json[prop].art == 'foo') && (db_json[prop].for_uid == user) ) {
                someArray1.push(db_json[prop]);
            } else if( (db_json[prop].art == 'foo') && (db_json[prop].uid == user) ) {
                someArray2.push(db_json[prop]);
            } else if( db_json[prop].art == 'log' ) {
                otherArray.push(db_json[prop]);
            }
        }

        if(someArray1.length>0) {
            someArray1.map(function(el){
                $('someArray1target').innerHTML += el.done;
                //do more stuff
            });
        }

        if(someArray2.length>0) {
            someArray2.map(function(el){
                $('someArray2target').innerHTML += el.done;
                //do more stuff
            });
        }   

});
```

Sometimes, it works perfectly.

Sometimes, i get my JSON String (it appears in Firebug's "answer"-tab), but it won't log the JSON in console-log(). I'm not getting any errors and javascript is still working.

Next time after reloading, it might work, but it might not.

I cannot remotely imagine why this only happens sometimes!

Comment: Does you JSON DEBUG always returns true? Can you provide us a link so we can try to debug it?

Comment: My "JSON DEBUG" is not even logged in the console when it fails. The last thing I see in Firebug is the ajax-request with a successful answer.
And I'm sorry, I can't provide a link, this runs on a non-public server.

Comment: does your server side script always return the same content-type header? this can affect the results of evalJSON

Comment: another thing, I would try to put the log statement before you set the variable db_json, and also try to log the string responseText directly, without eval'ing.

Comment: My script always returns the same content-type header. I've also tried to remove all console.log()'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It makes me want to slam my head. My $('someArray1target') div sometimes was not loaded yet.

I was so focused in finding something weird in my JSON instead of searching for the more obvious, "standard" errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling evalJSON twice, actually with different parameters each time.
Normally, I wouldn't expect this to have any side-effects, and indeed the prototype documentations for this method don't mention any. However, I remember that earlier versions of firebug were known to manipulate the XMLHttpRequest in weird ways (in order to capture the data going in and out), so maybe this is still relevant today.

Try changing the log statement to this instead:

```
console.log(db_json);
```

Comment: Nope :( still gets stuck sometimes